# Which is a preferred framework, approach for building a custom web application with self managed User roles, permissions in Java ?

Tags: java, gwt, frameworks, permissions, enterprise

I need to find and select a framework with following capabilities to support web application development in java that need extensive

> User management with custom roles, permissions with ability to define, manage those. 
>   Easy Administration support
>   Integration with LDAP / ADFS / CAS capabilities
>   Multi tenancy support
>   Top level entity support along side multi tenancy such as each silo / tenant can have multiple projects

We have chosen GWT as a client side development framework.

We need to be able to restrict the actions visible to an end user based on his permissions / roles (multiple)

Any recommendations of framework / approaches / schema will be helpful.

We intend to build two releases to support RDBMS & No SQL databases.

Is there a readymade admin portal available to provide along with my application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpringSecurity and Apache Shiro are two good starting points that have excellent intergration with LDAP / CAS ... etc.

Spring Security has an ACL module which I have found to be useless for my application since I have some very complex security requirements. So I ended up rolling my own authorization framework which is based on RBAC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control it is not too hard to roll your own but you really need to decide what type of security paradigm you want to use MAC/DAC/RBAC/ACL/Attribute based access control.

as for the RDBMS vs. No SQL I don't think that should be an issue if you roll your own. In my case I am using postgres and store all my permissions in there. I also need multi tenancy and so for each company in my system I create an Authorizer Object and cache it. The Authorizer and all the objects it depends on are true immutable objects and have data structures to answers security questions super fast in most cases it O(1) worst cases O(n)

I found the google Guava library very handy to use for the caching and for the many immutable data structures that are built into it.

Spring Security does not have a built in portal for managing permissions, I don't know about Apache shiro.

Answer (score 0):

As we are having the same thing going on here, I recommend you to use Spring Security framework. You can configure it that way to have roles and resources assigned dynamically.

Although Spring Security does not have any portal for managing permissions, but you can have it by using some simple filters and customizing some classes.